# buffer by objectid in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, objectid

is there a way in Arcpy (arcgis 10.2.1) to buffer lines by selecting thier objectid?

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("MY_JUNK","d:/data/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/MY_JUNK_Buffer1","10 Meters","FULL","ROUND","NONE","#")
```

Currently the copout is to manually select the objects but they are changing over time and it is easier to select by objectid if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like this:

Select Layer By Attribute Example (Python Window)

```
import arcpy
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("C:/data/data.mdb/states", "stateslyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("stateslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", " [OBJECTID] = 12345 OR 12346")
```

Then run the buffer.